# How to Make Samba List All Shares Without Authentication

Tags: samba

*edit: I just created a Windows 7 VM, and everything works exactly as I want it to from there. So it looks like this is a recent Windows 10+ client thing and not a Samba issue. Apparently there's more to it than just "Enable insecure guest logons" involved.*

Samba 4.19.5 on Opensuse Tumbleweed, server name HOGSTORE.

A large number of Windows 10 Pro (22H2) desktops as clients on workgroup 802MAGIC.

I want all browseable shares on this server to be visible (not necessarily accessible) without a username/password prompt in Windows Explorer. When accessing \\HOGSTORE, I want all the shares that are set as "browseable" to be listed, but and NO prompt for credentials. Some of the shares may or may not require authentication to access.

I've been trying for days to get this to work, unsuccessfully. It always prompts for credentials . Here's what I've tried so far:

- turned on "Enable insecure guest logons" in Windows 10 using group policy editor.
- ensured that "Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always)" is disabled in Windows 10 using group policy editor (it already was by default on every client).
- created a user on the server called "weaksauce" in group "weaksauce" with no password (I explicitly deleted its password using `passwd -d weaksauce`, and then for good measure also deleted its password with `smbpasswd -n weaksauce`. Tried with login shell set as both /bin/bash and /bin/nologin.
- ensured the Samba server and all clients are on the same workgroup.
- here's my smb.conf global section:

```
[global]
log level = 3
workgroup = 802MAGIC
netbios name = HOGSTORE
guest account = weaksauce
server string = SMB Server %v
case sensitive = no
map to guest = bad user
guest ok = yes
invalid users = root
eventlog list = Application System Security SyslogLinux
server role = standalone server
preferred master = yes
log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
usershare allow guests = Yes
load printers = no
```

- Ensured the Windows 10 Pro client was rebooted after changes, and the Samba server was restarted to reload configuration changes.

I don't know what magic setting(s) is(are) needed for this to function, but the frustration of trying to get it to function as needed has caused me to rip out all my hair and I'm now completely bald. I've scoured the Googles and none of the results I've come across have helped me solve this (obviously, since I'm here now).

Really hoping someone can help me out or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Worth noting that I also tried all this with the built-in user "nobody" and it didn't work, which is what led me to trying it with a new user "weaksauce", instead

Comment: `point me in the right direction.` check the logs on the samba server. It should show the access denied event, specifically the credentials used. You don't know if the endpoint is attempting guest access (likely not) or if it is presenting the credentials of the logged on user, which is the default behavior of Windows.

Comment: Shouldn't either of those things result in Samba mapping the incorrect authentication attempt to the specified guest user account (in this case, "weaksauce")? My understanding is that this is the entire point of the `map to guest = bad user` setting, where a bad user automatically gets relegated to the specified guest account. Therefore even if there was an unsuccessful login attempt, that's kinda what I want

Comment: You asked to be pointed in the right direction. Your server has logs. In those logs are the identity that failed. We don't have those logs.

Comment: And there is an event log entry on the client to confirm in Microsoft-Windows-SMBClient.

Answer (score 2):

So you have likely run into an issue with Windows 10 Pro and more recent versions, explictly protecting against the exact thing you are trying to do.

Windows by default does not allow accessing SMB services via what it views as insecure guest access. There are two ways to change this.

First, is a way to do this if you have already installed/enabled gpedit, which is tricky in Windows 10 Pro and not covered here:

```
Run: gpedit.msc
Go to: Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Lanman Workstation
Enable: "Enable insecure guest logons"
```

The other option is in the registry editor:

```
Run: regedit
Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\LanmanWorkstation
Click: Edit -> New -> DWORD (32-bit) Value
Name it: AllowInsecureGuestAuth
Set value to: 1
Exit Registry Editor
Reboot
```

At this point, with either method, you should be able to see secured shares without a username and password. HOWEVER, please note there is no "guest" option when authenticating by default. So, it MAY still ask you for a username/password. If it does, enter in anything. It doesn't matter. When it fails, the server will use the 'map to guest' setting and fall back to the guest user and allow visibility.

Good luck and let me know if this works!

Comment: While I appreciate the effort to provide a thorough answer, if you read through my initial question, you'll see that I already did that and it hasn't worked. I had high hopes that it would.

Comment: This is indeed the likely cause. I have provided more information in another response. The client side SMBClient event log can be used to confirm. And there are two registry keys/value locations.

Comment: This may have something to do with the continuing lack of NetBIOS support in recent Windows builds. I'm experimenting with broadcasting my Linux SAMBA server to Windows via the 'wsdd' (Web Service Discovery Daemon) system. Something worth looking into.

Comment: My apologies, I thought I read it carefully but I missed the very first bullet point. That said, I have tried this myself in a test environment and it led from the behavior you described to full functionality.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/guest-access-in-smb2-is-disabled-by-default

**Guest access in SMB2 and SMB3 disabled by default in Windows**

This article describes information about Windows disabling guest access in SMB2 and SMB3 by default, and provides settings to enable insecure guest logons in Group Policy. However, this is generally not recommended.

Original KB number:   4046019

**Symptoms**

Starting from Windows 10, version 1709 and Windows Server 2019, SMB2 and SMB3 clients no longer allow the following actions by default:

- Guest account access to a remote server.
- Fall back to the Guest account after invalid credentials are provided.

SMB2 and SMB3 have the following behavior in these versions of Windows:

- Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Education no longer allow a user to connect to a remote share by using guest credentials by default, even if the remote server requests guest credentials.
- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and Standard editions no longer allow a user to connect to a remote share by using guest credentials by default, even if the remote server requests guest credentials.
- Windows 10 Home and Pro are unchanged from their previous default behavior; they allow guest authentication by default.
- Windows 11 Insider Preview Build 25267 Pro editions no longer allow a user to connect to a remote share by using guest credentials by default, even if the remote server requests guest credentials. All subsequent Windows 11 Insider Preview builds no longer allow a user to connect to a remote share by using guest credentials by default.

If you try to connect to devices that request credentials of a guest instead of appropriate authenticated principals, you may receive one of the following error messages:

- You can't access this shared folder because your organization's security policies block unauthenticated guest access. These policies help protect your PC from unsafe or malicious devices on the network.
- Error code: 0x80070035
  The network path was not found.

Also, if a remote server tries to force you to use guest access, or if an administrator enables guest access, the following entries are logged in the SMB Client event log:

```
Log Name: Microsoft-Windows-SmbClient/Security  
Source: Microsoft-Windows-SMBClient  
Date: Date/Time  
Event ID: 31017  
Task Category: None  
Level: Error  
Keywords: (128)  
User: NETWORK SERVICE  
Computer: ServerName.contoso.com  
Description: Rejected an insecure guest logon.  
User name: Ned  
Server name: ServerName
```

**Guidance**

This event indicates that the server tried to log on the user as an unauthenticated guest but was denied by the client. Guest logons don't support standard security features such as signing and encryption. So, guest logons are vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks that can expose sensitive data on the network. Windows disables insecure (nonsecure) guest logons by default. We recommend that you don't enable insecure guest logons.

**Cause**

This change in default behavior is by design and is recommended by Microsoft for security.

A malicious computer that impersonates a legitimate file server could allow users to connect as guests without their knowledge. We recommend that you don't change this default setting. If a remote device is configured to use guest credentials, an administrator should disable guest access to that remote device and configure correct authentication and authorization.

Windows client and Windows Server haven't enabled guest access or allowed remote users to connect as guest or anonymous users since Windows 2000. Only third-party remote devices might require guest access by default. Microsoft-provided operating systems don't.

**Resolution**

Configure your third-party SMB server device to require a username and password for SMB connections. If your device allows guest access, any device or person on your network can read or copy all of your shared data without any audit trail or credentials.

If you can't configure your third-party device to be secure, you can enable insecure guest access with the following Group Policy settings:

1. Open the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) on your Windows device.
2. In the console tree, select Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > Lanman Workstation.
3. For the setting, right-click Enable insecure guest logons and select Edit.
4. Select Enabled > OK.

For monitoring and inventory purposes, this group policy sets the following DWORD registry value to 1 (insecure guest auth enabled) or 0 (insecure guest auth disabled):

> Key: HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\LanmanWorkstation

> Value: AllowInsecureGuestAuth

To set the value without using Group Policy, use the following registry value:

> Key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters

> Value: AllowInsecureGuestAuth

**Note**

As usual, the value setting in Group Policy will override the value setting in the non-Group Policy registry value. (Check both during investigation).

**More information**

This setting has no effect on SMB1 behavior. SMB1 continues to use guest access and guest fallback.